# Redirect to latest post

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, redirect

I want to redirect visitors of my `wordpress` blog to `latest single post`.
i can't find a plugin and don't know how to do this!

e.g. `www.example.com --> www.example.com/?p=123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick [google search](http://italkless.com/redirect-your-visitors-to-latest-post-instead-of-wordpress-homepage.html) will help you.
Put this code at the top of your `index.php` or home page, above the `get_header()` function.

```
<?php
/*
index.php (Blog Home Page):
Redirect To First Post
*/

if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        wp_redirect(get_permalink());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i found something here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/only-show-latest-post-and-comments-on-front-page

Comment: but NOW i want to redirect to custom post type! e.g.
`www.example.com/?product=432`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing a select MAXID from the WP content table then using that id in your redirect which will be the latest post.

Or

I believe there is a setting in wordpress to make the homepage the latest post.

Comment: Logically correct, though an overkill since WP provides a built in function.

Answer (score 0):

add_action('wp_head','hook_css');

```
function hook_css() {
if( is_front_page() ) {
$latest = get_posts( "post_type=post&numberposts=1" );
$permalink = get_permalink( $latest[0]->ID );
$output="<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='4;url=" . $permalink . "'/>";

echo $output;

}}
```